# different definition of simple radical extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Usual definition of simple radical definition is that:field extension F(α),α^n∈F for some n.

But in our abstract algebra textbook,it says that the above n is the degree of α.

I don't quite understand if the two definition are equivalent or not...And if not,why it says that?

Comment: The $n$ is the degree; the $F(\alpha)$ is the radical extension.  So no, they are defining two different things.

Comment: @Alex Imposing that $a^n \in F$ where $n = [F(a):F]$ makes cyclotomic extensions such as $\Bbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi /5})/\Bbb{Q}$ non-radical

Comment: If $a^p \in F$ with $p$ prime then either $p=[F(a):F]$ or $a$ is in the splitting field of $x^p-1\in F[x]$. Next we need Hilbert 90 to know the $a$ in the splitting field of $x^p-1$ such that $a^p\in F$.